# ggmap Plot by City over Lat/Long

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap

I'm trying to create a map using `ggmap` that plots circles on the coordinates of different cities with a value input as the diameter/radius.

```
City         Diameter/Radius
Atlanta      100000
Chicago      200000
New York     300000
Los Angeles  400000
Miami        500000
```

I have achieved this in the past, but I had to index/match city names to the `zipcode` data set that contained a list of approximately 3000 cities and their lat/long sets. See below for aggregated data set:

```
     Date          city Total.Conversions      lat       long    newdate
1  6/7/15       Chicago            132726 41.85000  -87.65000 2015-06-07
2 6/11/15      New York            118858 40.75074  -73.99653 2015-06-11
3 6/10/15       Houston             98766 40.24185  -80.21445 2015-06-10
4 5/25/15       Atlanta             95496 42.56055  -77.47257 2015-05-25
5  6/8/15        Dallas             93477 41.34558  -75.97596 2015-06-08
6 6/12/15 San Francisco             88536 37.78483 -122.72780 2015-06-12
```

Although this seemed like a good idea at first, there was some data loss and overall the outputs weren't correct. The code and output looked like so:

```
map <- get_map(location=c(lon = -98.35, lat = 39.50), zoom = 4, source="google",maptype="roadmap",crop=FALSE)
ggmap(map)
ggmap(map, legend = "none")+geom_point(aes(x = testdata$long, y = testdata$lat), data = testdata, alpha = .7, 
                      color = "darkgreen", size = (testdata$Total.Conversions)/5000)
```

[image: ggMap]

**Is there any way to plot data by using city names/DMAs/states rather than using lat/long coordinates?** If so, what is the best way to approach this situation? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: um, the cities have to be converted to lat/lon at some point.

Comment: so the way I've been doing it in the past is the only way of doing it?